# Error al crear tablas

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente error **Can't create table 'base1.articulos' (errno: 150)**
al pasar el comando create tabla a mi base de datos, lo cual no me deja crear la tabla posts dentro de ella

```
CREATE TABLE `articulos` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `body` text NOT NULL,
 `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

ese es mi comando para sql.

Comment: tienes una foreign key apuntando a users, tengo duda para el momento que creas la tabla articulos, ya declaraste la tabla users? es decir tu orden debe ser primero la tabla users y luego la de articulos

Comment: yo te recomendaría que quites las claves foraneas, es un tema complejo si no sabes majarlo muy bien. te recomiendo que crees la tabla sin las claves foraneas y luego la agreges manualmente.

Comment: Como comenta shadow, la tabla `users` debe crearse primero que `articulos`, y debe ser también `InnoDB`, mientras que la columna `id` debe ser del mismo tipo en ambas tablas. @Matias no me parece una buena sugerencia lo que comentas. Si se va a trabajar con bases de datos y no se entienden las claves foráneas la solución no es crear tablas sin llaves foráneas, sino aprender cómo funcionan... hay bastante documentación para hacerlo. Si se crean las tablas a la ligera, querer poner restricciones luego que haya datos va a ser mucho más complicado.

Comment: Si amigo, se me habia pasado! jajaja gracias por el comment como siempre ! abrazos @A.Cedano

Comment: De nada Ricardo. ¿Pudiste resolverlo? ¿Cuál era el problema de todo lo que hemos mencionado?

Comment: @A.Cedano correcto amigo, estaba haciendo references a una tabla user "inexistente" jajaja como no lo pense. disculpa estoy aprendiendo php haciendo.

Comment: @A.Cedano, habra alguna manera de tener en el index.php solo 3 post como "mas recientes" hago un loop o manejo una nueva funcion